# BigQuery data migration on Java

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I have two BigQuery connections:

1. Client BiqQuery connection (with read only permissions)
2. Application BigQuery connection.

Both connections (BiqQuery services) have a lot of Datasets.
So, I created two beans (repositories) with different credentials (client and application).

I need execute query in **Client BigQuery service**, get result from query (I got it in **GetQueryResultsResponse** ) and transfer it to **Application BigQuery service** like new Table.

I tried to create new table in **Application BigQuery service** using table scheme from **GetQueryResultsResponse** and after I had executed query I added new Row to the table. But in this case I have issue - inserting in BigQuery doesn't accomplish instantly. Data is added for some time and I need data right after the insertion.

Questions:
Perhaps is there a way to save this data to a file and use it in the future?
Is there a way to transfer data from query result from one Google BigQuery service to another?

> My code:

```
//get data from client service
GetQueryResultsResponse resultsResponse = executeQuery(query);
TableSchema schema = resultsResponse.getSchema();
Table table = new Table();
table.setSchema(schema);

TableReference tableRef = new TableReference();
tableRef.setDatasetId(applicationDataSetId);
tableRef.setProjectId(projectId);
tableRef.setTableId(tableId);
//create new table in Application BigQuery environment
try {
Bigquery.Tables.Insert insert = getApplicationBigQueryService().tables().insert(projectId, applicationDataSetId, table);
insert.execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
}

TableDataInsertAllRequest content = new TableDataInsertAllRequest();
List<TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows> bigQueryRows = new ArrayList<>();

List<Map<String, Object>> rows2 = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, Object> tableCell = new TableCell();
tableCell.put("customer_master_id", 1);
tableCell.put("formulary_name", "FOR");
tableCell.put("quarter", "2014");
tableCell.put("lives", 1234213);
tableCell.put("source", "BOT");


TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows row = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();
row.setJson(tableCell);
bigQueryRows.add(row);

TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows insertRows = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();

insertRows.setJson(tableCell);
bigQueryRows.add(insertRows);

content.setRows(bigQueryRows);
// send insert request to BigQuery
Bigquery.Tabledata.InsertAll request = getBentoBigQueryService().tabledata().insertAll(projectId, bentoDataSetId,tableId, content);

//insert data to table
TableDataInsertAllResponse response = request.execute();
log.info(response.toString());
if (response.containsKey(INSERT_ERRORS)) {
throw new JobException(String.format(ERROR_SYNC_MSG, response));
}
} catch (IOException ex) {
log.warn(ERROR_SYNC_MSG, ex);
throw new JobException(String.format(ERROR_SYNC_MSG, ex.getMessage()));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd way to move data around inside BigQuery.  If you look at the many options you can set for a query, you can explicitly have the results materialized to a named destination table, and setting appropriate create/write dispositions will govern whether whether data is appended or replaced in the destination.

Assuming you have the appropriate permissions for the source (reading) and destination (writing), this can be done between datasets and projects.

If you're not manipulating schema or results with the query and simply copying data, you may also want to look at table copy jobs.

Comment: I know several ways how to do this with let's say one BigQuery credentials, which create connection. Main problem, any of these 'credential' don't have permission to another service. I couldn't execute query using customer credentials and insert result to application BigQuery because customer service don't have permission to do this. It looks like: Bigquery.Jobs.Query bigQuery = getBigQueryService().jobs().query(projectId, queryRequest);
getBigQueryService() - client big query connection object
getApplicationBigQueryService() - application big query connection object.Can you give an example?